# Can an F# generic type constraint specify more than 1 valid type?

Tags: generics, f#

I have this sample function signature:

```ml
let func1 (input:'a when 'a :> (IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>)) =
...
```

I would also like to permit `'a` to be an `IDictionary<string, string>)`. So either type could be passed. The code that uses the `input` parameter calls `TryGetValue` which both interfaces support.

Is it possible to specify an OR type constraint like this? If so, what is the specific syntax to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, but you can use [SRTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) to require the `TryGetValue` method:

```ml
let inline func1 (input : 'a when 'a : (member TryGetValue : string * byref<string> -> bool)) =
    let mutable value = ""
    let flag = input.TryGetValue("key", &value)
    flag, value
```

It's ugly, but it works. Here it's called with an `IDictionary`:

```ml
dict [ "key", "value" ]
    |> func1
    |> printfn "%A"   // (true, "value")
```

And here it's called in an `IReadOnlyDictionary`:

```ml
dict [ "key", "value" ]
    |> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary
    :> System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<_, _>
    |> func1
    |> printfn "%A"   // (true, "value")
```

Comment: Indeed. One might write `let func1 (input: 'a when 'a :> (IReadOnlyDictionary<string,string>) and 'a :> (IDictionary<string,string>)) =` but it won't work because the two interfaces are not implemented at the same time, even for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>`. And disjunction in type constraints is not allowed. Thus picking the members you need as is shown above should work. And you can use the `and` construct to combine multiple such member constraints.

Comment: @brian-berns  This worked perfectly! I was happy to learn how to specify the constraint for the `TryGetValue` method. I tried but couldn't figure out the part about the out value.  I definitely wandered into deep end with this.  I notice that in F# the Try type methods from the .NET framework are rewritten or recompiled automatically to return a tuple of bool * T instead of using the out value method. I guess the compiler wouldn't know about a case like this, so it's interesting to learn that F# can do out values when necessary.